# Is there a way to use environment variables within strings on asp.net json files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

On the project debug settings, I have my environment variables set to this:

```
CUSTOMCONNSTR_csc380db : Server=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=csc380db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SA;Password=P@SSW0RD;
```

On appsettings.json, I have my connection strings set to nothing since the environment variable will update it:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "csc380db": ""
  }
```

These configurations work just fine. What I'm trying to accomplish here is by having an environment variable for each property (Server, User ID, Password, etc) within that string instead of for the entire string of "csc380db".

I've tried making more environment variables by appending the properties like this but it's not working:

```
CUSTOMCONNSTR_csc380db_Server : localhost,1433
CUSTOMCONNSTR_csc380db_USER ID : SA
```

Comment: I don't think that environment variables work on this way. You can declare every property separately and concatenate in code

Comment: Pls follow the link to add it efficiently 
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/aspnet-core-environment-variable#:~:text=ASP.NET%20Core%20uses%20an,is%20case%20sensitive%20on%20Linux.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Can you post an example? I don't think I can concatenate within json.

Comment: @SamimHussain I know how to add an environment variable, not what I'm asking.